# Connection reset error while uploading video on S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I want to upload large video in s3 using s3_multipart rails gem. I've added below CORS Configuration in AWS S3 bucket and change permission as everyone(Public).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I've upload 50MB video it's calls onStart and onProgress method of s3_multipart and try to do connection with S3 bucket but it's not working.

I'm getting error as following

```
"PUT  https://dead-radio.s3.amazonaws.com/b98c05b0-b6ed-0135-1be0-7caa145ace4b/642519614.mp4?partNumber=1&uploadId=WDawyHPnFveTAY8L8jipTI2RQFIgxn09uNGoHYf489_ZDAc7ZCb1taVYMCyO.TAyTIU.pMT.rrlXsvtO1wFs0Q--  net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"
```

Looking forward to best solution as soon as possible.

Comment: please show some  code of  how you are uploading

Comment: I've followed s3_multipart gem and link is https://github.com/maxgillett/s3_multipart